# how to update my location every x time or every triger if its posible

Tags: android, firebase, location

i trying develop app that get my location and write it to firebase every x hours or when my phone is wake

i try to this with work manager but to get location i need to pass activity to the worker class, and i don't know how to do this.

when i try to cast the context to activity i get multi dex exeption

this is from main activity

```
        PeriodicWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateWorker.class,3, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(workerData)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

and this is from my worker class

```
public UpdateWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) context.getApplicationContext(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        db.collection(USERS).document(user.getEmail())
                                .set(new LocationDoc(user.getUid(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),
                                        SetOptions.merge());
                    }
                }
            });

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: The `getApplicationContext()` is not the activity context as used here - it is the global application context and so cannot be cast to Activity: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()

Comment: so how i can pass my activity to my worker class??

Comment: An `Activity` is a `Context` so just use `this` in the `getInstance(this)`.

Comment: i tried this but it still gives me multidex exeption

Comment: You would also have to modify the `addOnSuccessListener` to just use `context` and not the application context.